# Youtube API: upload a remote video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was able to programmatically upload a local video to youtube using the example at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert.

However, when I try to upload a remote video file, I get the following error message:

“A service error occurred: Failed to parse Content-Range header”

I want to use a full url instead of a path here:

$videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";

vs.

$videoPath = "http:www.example.com/path/to/file.mp4";

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported as of now. Even the main Youtube channel website asks you to upload a video from your device (PC/mobile) and not from a remote URL.